# How can I set the background color of some special row in QTableView?

Tags: c++, qt, colors, row, qt5

I read an older post however that is not work for me.

I would like to set the background color of every row whose 6th argument is true.
I tried to overwrite the Paint method in my subclass of QSqlRelationalDelegate but apparently it does not do anything.

```
MoviesDelegate::MoviesDelegate(QObject *parent)
    : QSqlRelationalDelegate(parent)
{ }

void MoviesDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter,
                           const QStyleOptionViewItem &option,
                           const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if( index.sibling( index.row(), 6 ).data().toBool() )
    {
        QStyleOptionViewItemV4 optionViewItem = option;
        optionViewItem.backgroundBrush = QBrush( Qt::yellow );

        drawDisplay( painter, optionViewItem,
                     optionViewItem.rect,index.data().toString() );
        drawFocus( painter, optionViewItem, optionViewItem.rect);
    }
    else
        QSqlRelationalDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
}
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why don't you use `QAbstractItemModel::data()` with `Qt::BackgroundRole` as the second argument?

Comment: You should not be using QItemDelegate for displaying ordinary data in a QAbstractItemView. It is used for the editor widget only. You should pass data back from your model if you want custom formatting to be used in your views. If the view doesn't handle certain roles, then you should customise the view. Delegates are only for editors, which are only temporary widgets used while editing and then destroyed.

Comment: If you don't want or cant for some reason use Qt::BackgroundRole of the model underlying your view, you can create an intermediate proxy model which will return appropriate colors for the rows you need to highlight

Answer (score 1):

```
void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    // Grab cell value and cast it to boolean
    bool boolValue = index.model()->data(index).toBool();

    // Paint cell background depending on the bool value
    if(boolValue)
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, QColor(179, 229, 255));
    else
        painter->fillRect(option.rect, Qt::red);

    // Paint text
    QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter, option, index);
}
```